# Plotting multiple graphs in a specific figure in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

so, I have a many figures and I want to select one of them and then plot into it another's graphs, how can I do that ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have the data or just the figures? Also have you looked at the `hold` and `subplot` functions?

Comment: subplot not convenient because I want to plot in the same figure.

Comment: suppose the I have figure 1 for position and figure 2 for velocity the question is I want to add anothor position curve to the first figure !!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: So if you have the data then you just want to call `hold on` after your first plot, and then just call `plot`again: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html?refresh=true. Also if you want Matlab to automatically manage the colours for you, call `hold all`instead.

Comment: but I want to do that automaticly inside a for loop

Comment: you should use `axes`, but show us what you tried to do

Comment: clc;clear;
a = [ 1.8 2.5 6.4 ] ; % acceleration
t = 0:.01:15 ;
n = 1 ;

while n < 4
    
    velocity = a(n)*t ;
    position = 0.5*a(n)*t.^2 + velocity.*t ;
    
    figure
    plot(t,velocity) ;
    figure
    plot(t,position) ;
    
     n = n + 1 ;
end

Comment: I don't know how to add a code !?

Comment: leave out the `figure` calls, and add `hold all` before the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally use `subplot` or `figure` and `hold all` in this situation.

Therefore, your code would look like:

```
clc;clear; a = [ 1.8 2.5 6.4 ] ; % acceleration 
t = 0:.01:15 ; n = 1 ; 
figure; 
while n < 4 
velocity = a(n)*t ; 
position = 0.5*a(n)*t.^2 + velocity.*t ; 
figure(1);plot(t,velocity);
hold all;
figure(2);plot(t,position);
n = n + 1 ; 
hold all;
end
hold off;
```

Comment: You mean separate figures for velocity and position? One figure for velocity curves and one for position curves?

Comment: If that is the case then you need to replace `subplot(2,1,1)` with `figure(1)` and `subplot(2,1,2)` with `figure(2)`. I just edited my answer for you to make more sense.

Comment: BTW, you can use `for n=1:3` loop instead of `while n<4` and remove `n=1` and `n=n+1`.